# How to store xml in list in Android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

```
 TextView Naziv[];
    TextView Id[];
    int a = 0;

    //ovaj primjer sam nasao na netu, treba parsirat XML
    //ali nisam siguran da li treba podatke parsirat u ovoj klasi ili u nekoj drugoj
    //probaj to skuzit


    try{
        String address = "http://www.dajsve.com/rss.ashx?svigradovi=1";
        URL gradoviXmlUrl = new URL(address);

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(gradoviXmlUrl.openStream());

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Grad");

        Naziv = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

        List<Grad> gradoviLista = null;

        for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++){
            Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
            NodeList nazivGrada = element.getElementsByTagName("Naziv");
            NodeList idGrada = element.getElementsByTagName("Id");
            Element nazivGradaElement = (Element) nazivGrada.item(i);
            Element idGradaElement = (Element) idGrada.item(i);
            String gradNaziv = nazivGradaElement.getAttribute("Naziv");


            /*Grad grad = null;
            grad.setNaziv(nazivGrada);
            grad.setId(idGradaElement);


            gradoviLista.add(idGradaElement, nazivGradaElement);*/

        }

        a = nodeList.getLength();
        //ovdje u varijablu zapisujem broj gradova, koje kasnije koristim samo za provjeru u main aktivitiju
```

The fetch from web service works, in variable a i store the length of elements, but the storing into variables does'nt work.

```
Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
            NodeList nazivGrada = element.getElementsByTagName("Naziv");
            NodeList idGrada = element.getElementsByTagName("Id");
            Element nazivGradaElement = (Element) nazivGrada.item(i);
            Element idGradaElement = (Element) idGrada.item(i);
            String gradNaziv = nazivGradaElement.getAttribute("Naziv");
```

This code does'nt work.

this is the xml: http://www.dajsve.com/rss.ashx?svigradovi=1
Can somebody help me?

Comment: what does the nodeList contain ?

Comment: all the elements from xml..

Comment: add your stack trace, you are probably having a classCastException right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodeList.item(i);` returns the node at the indexth position in the `NodeList`, a Node is not always an element so you will get a `ClassCastException` on:

```
Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
```

Just make sure to check `if(FPN.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)` before casting a `Node` to an `Element`

Or you can use:

```
Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            String gradNaziv  = getNodeValueByTagName(node ,"Naziv");
```

Comment: i was trying something like that, but still is'nt working. Can u write the code for my example..getNodeValueByTagName does'nt exist..

Comment: what are your imports, its probably the wrong class